# Search for Pdf Library on Linux (convert to image and merge multipages to one pdf)

Tags: pdf

I'm coding by PHP. Iam searching a PDF library that **converts pdf to image fastest on Linux** and **merge multipages to one pdf**

I tried imagick, but that's very slow.

Anyone can suggest for me ? Thank you

Comment: [pdftk](http://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/) is very good, but it may only do multipages -> one pdf

Comment: Thank you, and to convert pdf to image ? (not imagick)

Answer (score 0):

This answer is 100% derived from answers to https://superuser.com/questions/185880/how-to-convert-a-pdf-document-to-png and [snapshot image from PDF document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/955238/snapshot-image-from-pdf-document), so credit to those authors.

To speed things up, start by first extracting only the pages you need with [pdftk](http://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/):

```
pdftk file.pdf cat 2 output page2_only.pdf
```

Then you could use either from [Poppler](http://poppler.freedesktop.org/)

```
pdftoppm -png myfile.pdf > myfile.png
```

or stick with [Imagemagick](http://www.imagemagick.org)

```
convert -geometry 1600x1600 -density 200x200 -quality 100 page2_only.pdf page_snapshot.jpg
```

Comment: Imagemagick is very slow, I search for the solution fastest possible. I will try Poppler. Thanks for your answer