# A better way to copy a page from a PDF document to a TBitmap?

Tags: delphi

I want to copy the image of a page from a PDF document to a TBitmap. I read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/955682/4759426). It didn't work right away; I had to add a wait after the `CopyToClipboard`:

```
  ClipBoard.Clear;
  PDPage.CopyToClipboard(PDRect, 0, 0, 100);
  repeat
    Sleep(100);
  until ClipBoard.HasFormat(cf_Bitmap);
  Bitmap.LoadFromClipboardFormat(cf_BitMap, ClipBoard.GetAsHandle(cf_Bitmap), 0);
```

But it's far from ideal. Firstly it's slow, and secondly if you want to use this for a batch the clipboard is off limits for other applications. Wouldn't there be a better way, which doesn't use the clipboard?

In [Acrobat's API documentation](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/iac_api_reference.pdf) I found the DrawEx method for a PDPage:

```
var
  hBitmap: THandle;
...
  hBitmap := CreateCompatibleBitmap(Bitmap.Handle, Bitmap.Width, Bitmap.Height);
  PDPage.DrawEx(hBitmap, 0, PDRect, 0, 0, 100);
```

I was hoping it would copy the page to the TImage.Picture.Bitmap I passed to the function. Instead the the page was drawn on the desktop, which led me to think that hBitmap was 0. Confirmed using debugger.

How can I fix this?

**edit**
*MBo* says that after creation the TBitmap already holds a compatible bitmap, so the `CreateCompatibleBitmap` may be superfluous. But then I still don't know what handle I should pass to DrawEx. I tried `Bitmap.Handle` but the resulting bitmap then is blank.

I also tried

```
var
   DC: HDC;
...
   DC := GetDC(Bitmap.Handle);
   try
     PDPage.DrawEx(DC, 0, PDRect, 0, 0, 100);
   finally
     ReleaseDC(Handle, DC);
   end;
```

but this also draws on the desktop.

Comment: The first DrawEx parameter in **window** handle, not bitmap's one. And forget about Timage for start.

Comment: @MBo How do I get this handle? (And I think the use of TImage is justified here: I want to show the bitmap on a form. Isn't that what you meant?)

Comment: Timage might be used at the final stage - draw TBitmap on it. Sorry, I have no adobe stuff (Acrobat) on my computer an cannot test. Note - after creation TBitmap already contains valid compatible bitmap

Comment: Does that mean I should call DrawEx with Bitmap.Handle as first parameter? I then get a blank image.

Comment: No. Perhaps you have to select bitmap.handle in device context of created auxiliary window and use handle of that window

Comment: I don't know this library, but reading the docs, the function seems to expect a HWND, although it also mentions HDC at some point. Assuming it really is a HWND, I'd try with the handle of a form or panel to see if drawing works at all. If that succeeds, I'd probably try the handle of a bitmap, or of a bitmap.canvas. If those don't work, I think I'd try to work out some dirty code to get the image from a form/control onto my bitmap.